# Echo variable columnwise

Tags: linux

Variable 1:

```
'file:'"$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP"'/GDFS_Off_Peak_Lkp.txt'
'file:'"$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP"'/mssu2_massched.mssulrm_lkup_'"$AI_PHASE"'.txt'
'file:'"${AI_SERIAL_TEMP}"
```

Variable 2:

```
$PRIVATE_SCRIPT/2_ctc_rpt_dds_extn_stage_load.ksh ${AI_SERIAL}/${AB_JOB}_dds_parm_extn_iri_ctc_rpt.dat _${DestType} ${CURR_TIME_STAMP}
$PRIVATE_SCRIPT/1_ctc_rpt_dds_extn_stage_to_base.ksh ${AI_SERIAL}/${AB_JOB}_ ${DestType} ${CURR_TIME_STAMP}
```

Variable 3:

```
TGDM01.T3113_DA_DLVR_SP a,
TGIDM01.T3121_RT_REQ_CHK b
TGIM01.T3121_RPT_RQ_CHK
```

I need to print/export variable 1,2,3 side by side column wise in a Microsoft Excel sheet.

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you need by giving an example.

Comment: Are those shell/php/perl/C variables? By "excel", do you mean the Microsoft Excel spreadsheet editing software? Why the "linux" tag? Does it have to work on any system that has Linux as its kernel like Android, Fedora, ChromeOS... ?

Comment: Looks like the second variable has one fewer line. Does that mean an empty B3 cell?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : Yes. The number of lines in all variables is not constant.

Comment: This is the same question as http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323616/ it appears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest to generate a file understood by Microsoft Excel is to use a CSV format as it's just text with a simple format. In the [standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) format, rows are newline delimited, cells are comma separated, with double quotes being used to quote fields that contain problematic characters like comma and newline, and where a double character itself is entered as a `""`.

One thing that the CSV file format doesn't specify is the character set being used in the text of the file. That has to be communicated via other means.

### Variable content as single cell

To output a CSV row with those 3 variables, all we need to do is:

- escape the `"` characters within the variables
- wrap that in double quotes
- join them with commas
- add a newline character.

The `printf` builtin of the `ksh93` shell, as the `%#q` format to output a string as a CSV field, so takes care of the first two points above for those values that need to be quoted. So in that shell, it's just:

```
 printf '%#q,%#q,%#q\n' "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
```

With `bash`/`zsh`/`ksh`, you can do that encoding by hand and quote every cell with:

```
 printf '"%s","%s","%s"\n' "${var1//\"/\"\"}" "${var2//\"/\"\"}" "${var3//\"/\"\"}"
```

POSIXly, you could use `awk` to do the encoding:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    for(i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) {
      gsub(/"/, "\"\"", ARGV[i])
      printf "%s\"%s\"", sep, ARGV[i]
      sep = ","
    }
    printf "\n"
  }' "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" > file.csv
```

On your input, all those give:

```
"'file:'""$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP""'/GDFS_Off_Peak_Lkp.txt'
'file:'""$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP""'/mssu2_massched.mssulrm_lkup_'""$AI_PHASE""'.txt'
'file:'""${AI_SERIAL_TEMP}""","$PRIVATE_SCRIPT/2_ctc_rpt_dds_extn_stage_load.ksh ${AI_SERIAL}/${AB_JOB}_dds_parm_extn_iri_ctc_rpt.dat _${DestType} ${CURR_TIME_STAMP}
$PRIVATE_SCRIPT/1_ctc_rpt_dds_extn_stage_to_base.ksh ${AI_SERIAL}/${AB_JOB}_ ${DestType} ${CURR_TIME_STAMP}","TGDM01.T3113_DA_DLVR_SP a,
TGIDM01.T3121_RT_REQ_CHK b
TGIM01.T3121_RPT_RQ_CHK"
```

### Each line of each variable as a spreadsheet cell

That gets more complicated as you also need to split the variables into its lines.

With `ksh93` and its `%#q` format:

```
IFS=
while
  found=false
  read -ru3 a && found=true
  read -ru4 b && found=true
  read -ru5 c || "$found"
do
  printf '%#q,%#q,%#q\n' "$a" "$b" "$c"
done 3<<< "$var1" 4<<< "$var2" 5<<< "$var3" > file.csv
```

With `bash`/`zsh`/`ksh`, you could also use paste to paste 3 streams consisting of the expansion of the variables where the `"` have been escaped:

```
paste -d '"",' - <(printf '%s\n' "${var1//\"/\"\"}") - \
               - <(printf '%s\n' "${var2//\"/\"\"}") - \
               - <(printf '%s\n' "${var3//\"/\"\"}") - < /dev/null > file.csv
```

which on your input would give:

```
"'file:'""$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP""'/GDFS_Off_Peak_Lkp.txt'","$PRIVATE_SCRIPT/2_ctc_rpt_dds_extn_stage_load.ksh ${AI_SERIAL}/${AB_JOB}_dds_parm_extn_iri_ctc_rpt.dat _${DestType} ${CURR_TIME_STAMP}","TGDM01.T3113_DA_DLVR_SP a,"
"'file:'""$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP""'/mssu2_massched.mssulrm_lkup_'""$AI_PHASE""'.txt'","$PRIVATE_SCRIPT/1_ctc_rpt_dds_extn_stage_to_base.ksh ${AI_SERIAL}/${AB_JOB}_ ${DestType} ${CURR_TIME_STAMP}","TGIDM01.T3121_RT_REQ_CHK b"
"'file:'""${AI_SERIAL_TEMP}""","","TGIM01.T3121_RPT_RQ_CHK"
```

Comment: well... its a giving me variable output in separated tabs in excel, but not the desired output due to looping. Getting multiple duplicates due to improper use of loop. Pleas help.

Comment: @GauravChavan, the ksh93 loop was completely wrong indeed. See edit.

Comment: Stephane Chazelas: wow. The above script worked just perfect. The only tweak i need is, the variable output in a single tab(cell). So basically, now each variable output line is getting stored in different cell, i need all lines of variable captured in a single cell.Is it possible?

Comment: @GauravChavan, if you only need each variable in its own cell, then it's a lot simpler. See edit. Next time, please make sure you properly specify your requirements.

Comment: chazelas: I had tried this earlier too, and the result is, it only exports the first line of variable than all lines.

Comment: @GauravChavan. It works fine for me with LibreOffice calc. Possibly Microsoft Excel doesn't support CSVs with newlines in the cells. You could always use libreoffice to convert to an OpenDocument spreadsheet (`unoconv -f ods file.csv`). Hopefully MS Excel supports that.

Comment: Chazelas: The logic works fine, but if the data contains multiple commas then it outputs it on difference cell (acting as delimiter) and not on single cell.